# getComputedStyle() and cssText in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

Please refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfbxk04f/) which illustrates the problem.

I am trying to get the `cssText` property of a `<div>` via `window.getComputedStyle(element)` ([which returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle)). This works just fine in Chrome (version right out of the repos), but it does not work in Firefox and IE10 and IE11. Actually, `cssText` is a property on the returned object, it's just an empty string.

It may not work in older versions of IE but I haven't tested it in those versions. I cannot seem to find any reference to this specifically not working in recent versions of IE. Actually [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533698(v=vs.85).aspx) has led me to believe that it SHOULD work when in fact it does not ("Sets or retrieves the persisted representation of the style rule"). I am trying a little rubber duck debugging here to see if there is something obvious I've missed, or perhaps it's the [VM images](http://modern.ie) I'm using to test code on IE. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: What I'm looking for specifically is a way to get a list of CURRENT styles applied to an element, as happens when getting `cssText` from the object returned by `getComputedStyle()` in Chrome, but which does not happen in Firefox or IE. To clarify, it appears using the `style.cssText` property of an element in IE retrieves a list of styles applied to an element via stylesheets, style tags, and inline style rules, but NOT styles which were applied programmatically via scripts. This may be by design and as intended, but: How can I replicate the behavior seen when using `cssText` from a CSSStyleDeclaration object in Chrome (as returned by `getComputedStyle()`), but in Internet Explorer and Firefox?

Comment: So you're saying that `cssText` property of the CSSStyleDeclaration object returned by `getComputedStyle()` only offers up styles which were applied due to stylesheets and style tags, but not for example scripts which change the element's style? I can get on board with that. However, using `element.style.cssText` doesn't give me any actual data (i.e. it's still an empty string) when trying to retrieve the current styles applied to an element. How can I replicate this desired behavior in IE, i.e. get a string containing all currently-applied styles, regardless of their source?

Comment: Actually, if what you described about `getComputedStyle()` were true, IE should put SOMETHING inside the `fooText` div in the fiddle I linked in my question, but this isn't the case. The `cssText` property does not contain any data, including styles which were applied via stylesheet, unless I'm mistaken about the way JSFiddle includes styles.

Comment: I am seeing empty responses for both Firefox and IE. Can you double-check Firefox, @Loj1k? [I created a test as well](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/008hmbLu/show/), but am not finding that Firefox passes.

Comment: You're right! I can't remember how I arrived at the conclusion that it worked in FF yesterday. Firefox doesn't populate `cssText` with anything (it's an empty string on the CSSStyleDeclaration object like with IE). What a mess. I'm reminded over the last two days why I left web development for the backend. It appears iterating through properties is the only cross-browser way to get a list of actual, current styles on an element. While I get the chance, @JonathanSampson, thanks for any effort you've put into making IE play well with others. IE10 and 11 are lightyears ahead of older versions. :)

Comment: With Firefox and IE both behaving the same way, it may be the case that Chrome is doing something it shouldn't. That being said, Chrome is a popular browser, and interop is important. I have opened an issue internally for our team to consider this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use node.currentStyle to access specific style properties which is much more reliable than cssText.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Notice in this example cssText doesn't provide the background color.  I'm not sure when runtimeStyle is supposed to work but it doesn't seem to work pre or post javascript manipulation. These are likely bugs in IE.

Note: The getComputedCSSText function is a quick hack for demonstration purposes and likely needs some modifications for use in a production environment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">

#MyStyle {

   background-color: #FF00FF;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">


getComputedCSSText = function (node) {
   var s = [];
   for (var propertyName in node.currentStyle) {

       if ("string" == typeof(node.currentStyle[propertyName]) && node.currentStyle[propertyName] != "") {
          s[s.length] = (propertyName.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(x) { return "-"+(x.toLowerCase())}))+": "+node.currentStyle[propertyName];
       }
   }

   return s.join('; ') + ";";
};



MyTest = function() {

    var node = document.getElementById('MyStyle');

    alert("[pre-js] runtimeStyle.width = " +node.runtimeStyle.width);
    alert("[pre-js] style.cssText = " + node.style.cssText);
    alert("[pre-js] currentStyle.width = " + node.currentStyle.width);
    alert("[pre-js] currentStyle.backgroundColor = " + node.currentStyle.backgroundColor);  


    node.style.width="99px";

    alert("[post-js] runtimeStyle.width = " +node.runtimeStyle.width);
    alert("[post-js] style.cssText = " + node.style.cssText);
    alert("[post-js] currentStyle.width = " + node.currentStyle.width);
    alert("[post-js] currentStyle.backgroundColor = " + node.currentStyle.backgroundColor);

    alert("[post-js] getComputedCSSText = " + getComputedCSSText(node));
};

</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1 id="MyStyle">FooBar!</h1>
<button onclick="MyTest()">Test</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It definitely looks like -- for now -- iterating over the properties of the CSSStyleDeclaration object returned by `getComputedStyle()` (which seems to just be an alias to the `currentStyle` property in IE) is the only reliable cross-browser way to get a string list of current styles applied to an element. Thanks for your suggestion.